# R2016a: error constructing class when package & class name are equal

Tags: matlab, oop

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
Rootdir
└── +PkgClsName
    └── @PkgClsName
        └── PkgClsName.m
```

`PkgClsName.m` contains the following:

```
classdef PkgClsName < handle

    methods

        % Constructor
        function obj = PkgClsName()            
        end

        % Deep-copy handle object
        function new_obj = copy(obj)             
            new_obj = PkgClsName.PkgClsName();                            
        end

    end

end
```

Then, in R2016a, the following happens:

```
>> T = PkgClsName.PkgClsName;
>> T.copy()

One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "_mcos_superclass_implicit_construct".

Error in PkgClsName.PkgClsName

Error in PkgClsName.PkgClsName/copy (line 11)
            new_obj = PkgClsName.PkgClsName();
```

This does **not** happen in R2010a, R2014a and R2017a, pointing to (yet another) bug in R2016a...

The issue is because the package and class name are identical; changing the naming scheme such that they differ, fixes the issue. However, since the package name and class name have to be used *explicitly* in all functions/classes using the class, these names are now hard-coded in at least 600 files. That, and I have similar constructions for several other classes...I'd rather leave this all intact.

I was hoping to find a patch for this, but could not; am I overlooking it? Did anyone else encounter this? Anyone knows of an easy fix?

Comment: This would probably be best answered by TMW. Since it's been patched they probably have good insight into the root cause & any potential workarounds.

Comment: @excaza yeah, I guess I should file a bug report...I was just hoping for a quicker workaround :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already reported as [bug report number 1314646](https://uk.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/search_results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_executed=1&keyword=_mcos_superclass_implicit_construct&release_filter=Exists%20in&release=264&selected_products=103&category_filter%5B%5D=1&commit=Search), present in R2015b and R2016a, and fixed in R2016b.

I'm afraid there's no workaround, other than to not use the same name for package and class.

Comment: ...well, urghh.